# update data-model with option id instead of option value in select dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am new to angular js. I have a json value based on which i will be populating my html. I need to populate a select dropdown with two options and make one auto selected based on the flag mentioned in the json.

Below is my json

```
$scope.alertdata=[{"Action": "1", "Name":"Peter"},{"Action": "2", "Name":"Steve"},{"Action": "3", "Name":"Khan"}]
```

My HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in alertdata">
    <td>
<select ng-model="data.Action">
                            <option ng-selected="data.Action == '1' " id="data.Action">Option1</option>
                            <option ng-selected="data.Action == '2' " id="data.Action">Option2</option>
                            <option ng-selected="data.Action == '3' " id="data.Action">Option3</option>
                            <option ng-selected="data.Action == '4' " id="data.Action">Option4</option>
                        </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

In the above HTML whenever i change my option in the dropdown my model is changed with the value of the option selected. Instead I want the id of the option to be updated in my model, since i require to process the updated model based on the new selection of option.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your html doesn't make sense. You have an array `data`, with multiple actions. Then you bind an `ng-model` to `data.Action`, which doesn't exist. Besides that, I can't see how your options make sense (with the `id` and the labels). Please explain exactly what you're trying to do, because it looks like you do it the wrong way.

Comment: Updated the above HTML. The options are hardcoded, I just have to auto select the option based on flag "Action" present in json. Whenever option is changed by user, i want the id of the option to be updated to the model, instead of the option text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular's `ng-options`, which automatically selects the correct one when the `ng-model` is pre-filled:

```
$scope.availableOptions = [
    { id: "1", name: "Option1" },
    { id: "2", name: "Option2" },
    { id: "3", name: "Option3" },
    { id: "4", name: "Option4" }
];
```

Then in your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in alertdata">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="data.Action"
                ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in availableOptions">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juy86p88/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Its working. According to my understanding, data.Action in ng-model abides to option.id mentioned in ng-options. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes that is correct, see [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for reference